# How to do this rotating titles animation in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, animation

I have 6 divs:

```
<div id="element1" class="animated">Title1</div>
<div id="element2" class="animated">Title2</div>
<div id="element3" class="animated">Title3</div>
<div id="element4" class="animated">Title4</div>
<div id="element5" class="animated">Title5</div>
<div id="element6" class="animated">Title6</div>
```

I need to show one at a time, except...

I am using [Animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/), and I want each one to use the `.flipInY` class to enter, and then 
the `.flipOutY` class to exit.

This all needs to loop infinitely, and the effect should almost be a rotating set of titles, except each should pause for 1 second in between flipping in and out.

I am using Angular and jQuery, so those are both available to use.  Except for ngAnimate, I do not wish to use that.

**[JS Fiddle to start with here](http://jsfiddle.net/cg0nsfu5/)**

Comment: Can we get a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cg0nsfu5/

Comment: I was able to do it pretty simple with ngAnimate - http://plnkr.co/edit/yUPS3Pb8Z3ErKRD9KNix?p=preview